# Ubuntu 14.04.4 Black Screen w/ non blinking underscore

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, virtualbox, vdi

I have been using Oracle VM VirtualBox to access my Ubuntu Desktop for some time now.

All of a sudden, when I load up my VM, I see a GRUB menu with options to load Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, and Memory Test.

I have selected Ubuntu and edit the commands before booting. From there a replace quiet splash with nomodset. The result is a black screen with a non blinking underscore.

I have also selected Advanced options for Ubuntu. From there I select on option with (recovery mode). The result is a black screen with a non blinking cursor.

I have had a friend send over his VM to my computer, just to see if it was a video issue (he has the same version) and his loads up.

When I start from an iso, I am able to see my VM hard disk mounted along with my home folder. Starting from scratch will be a last resort because my computer was set up by someone who is no longer with the company. So trying to figure out what needs to be installed will be a pain.

I am at a total loss because I am not able to do anything outside of the grub menu interface. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Attached is the VM log as well as a screenshot of my VM settings.

The host machine is Windows 7 (if that matters)

Virtual Box ver. 5.0.18 r106667

Ubuntu 14.04.4

Thank in advanced.

[VM Log](http://pastebin.com/9YYU7ZXb)

[VM Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HglN.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Well, after reading the VM log, I saw that the first line read

"VirtualBox VM 5.0.18 r106667 win.amd64 (Apr 18 2016 14:31:52) release log"

And my VM settings were configured to Ubuntu (32-bit). After changing the settings from Ubuntu (32-bit) to Ubuntu (64-bit) everything booted up and works like it should.

As in most cases - "User Error". Hope this helps someone who maybe overlooking something so simple.

Great day.